# OpenShift, How to work with DIY in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, openshift

I installed Eclipse plugin for openShift and I created a Tomcat 8 DIY on OpenShift, but being new to OpenShift, I can't find any tutorials to work with a DIY, Any help?

PS: I noticed that by choosing an openshift server like tomcat 7 or 6, when we clone the repo, it contains a deployement repository..., but with DIY, I have only a misc and diy repository, so how can I deploy a war file?

Answer (score 0):

It might help to read through this blog article on using Tomcat 8 on OpenShift: https://blog.openshift.com/how-to-run-apache-tomcat-8-on-openshift/